# Floor function: Maths Olympiad problem

Tags: proof-explanation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, monotone-functions, interval-arithmetic

Hey I started working on the following problem:

For any real number $x$ let $\lfloor x \rfloor$,denote the greatest integer, which is less than or equal to $x$. Define $q(n) = \lfloor \frac{n}{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor} \rfloor $ for $n = 1,2,3,...$. Determine all positive integers $n$ for which $q(n)>q(n+1)$.

My attempt:

So I realised that $q(n)$ 'jumps' whenever $n$ moves from a number just below a perfect square to the next perfect square.

This gave me the idea to focus on values of $n$, between $m^2$ and $(m+1)^2$, in order to find out more about the function.

From $m^2 \le n < (m+1)^2$, we can deduce that $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor = m$. However now I am  stuck on how to continue with $q(n) = \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \rfloor$.

It seems to me that the function is increasing, but if yes then wouldn't there be no values for $n$ at all?

Can anyone help me on how to continue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the function is increasing in the interval $[m^2,(m+1)^2-1]$, so there are no values of $n$ in any interval $[m^2,(m+1)^2-1)$ which satisfies $q(n)>q(n+1)$, for any $m$. This means you only need to check $n=(m+1)^2-1$, for any $m$, because this is where $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ "jumps" when you move from $n$ to $n+1$.

For $n=(m+1)^2-1$, you have $q(n)=\lfloor\frac{m^2+2m}{m}\rfloor$ and $q(n+1)=\lfloor\frac{m^2+2m+1}{m+1}\rfloor$. Can you compare the two?

Comment: Where does the $(m+1)^2 - 1$ come from?

Comment: For $n=m^2,m^2+1,\dots,(m+1)^2-2$, we already have $q(n)\leq q(n+1)$, by the argument that you wrote.

Comment: Maybe an example would help. Consider $m=2$, so the interval $[4,8]$. For $n=4,5,6,7$, we already know that $q(n)\leq q(n+1)$. So we only need to check $n=8$, i.e., whether $q(8)>q(9)$ or not.

Comment: Well $q(n)  = \lfloor \frac{m^2 + 2m}{m} \rfloor = m+2$ and $q(n+1) = \lfloor \frac{(m+1)(m+1)}{(m+1)} \rfloor = m+1$

Comment: Right, exactly!

Comment: So I don't need to give concrete values for $n$?

Comment: This already allows you to conclude that the values of $n$ satisfying $q(n)>q(n+1)$ are $n=(m+1)^2-1$ for $m=1,2,3,\dots$

Comment: Ah thanks I see; So the crux step for this problem was determining that we only need to check between a perfect square and the number before it?

Comment: Right. And you did that part already :)

Answer (score 3):

The function $q(n)$ is piecewise increasing (but not strictly) in every interval $[m^2, {(m + 1)}^2 - 1]$, since if $a, b$ are in that interval (with $a < b$), then
$$\left\lfloor\frac a m \right\rfloor = q(a) \leq q(b) = \left\lfloor \frac b m \right\rfloor.$$

Therefore we only need to check where all those intervals "join", and that happens between a perfect square and the preceding number. Indeed we have $q(n) > q(n + 1)$ in this case:
$$q(m^2) = \left\lfloor\frac{m^2}m\right\rfloor = m$$
while
$$q(m^2 - 1) = \left\lfloor\frac{m^2 - 1}{m - 1}\right\rfloor = m + 1$$

We conclude that the only values of $n$ for which $q(n) > q(n + 1)$ are
$$\{m^2 - 1 \mid m \in \mathbb N\} = \{3, 8, 24, \ldots\}$$

I find that plotting the sequence really helps in visualizing the proof:
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me please what have you plot ?

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis I plotted $q(n)$ with $n$ from $1$ to $40$. The red points are the values of the sequence.

Comment: I see ... and how you calculate 
\begin{equation}
q(m^2 +1 )=\floor{\frac{m^2 -1 }{\floor{\sqrt(m^2 -1) } } }
\end{equation} 
at the formula which you wrote ?

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis Assuming you mean $q(m^2 - 1)$, we have:
$$q(m^2 - 1) = \left\lfloor\frac{m^2 - 1}{\lfloor\sqrt{m^2 - 1}\rfloor}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{m^2 - 1}{m - 1}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{(m + 1)(m - 1)}{m - 1}\right\rfloor = m + 1$$

Comment: Yeah that's what i meant . So can you explain how you figure out that $\lfloor \sqrt{m^2 -1} \rfloor  = m-1$

Comment: For example $\lfloor \sqrt{2^2 -1} \rfloor = 1  $ ????

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis We have that $\lfloor\sqrt{m^2}\rfloor = m$, because $\sqrt{m^2} = m$, if $m$ is positive, which in this case it is. Now, ${(m - 1)}^2 \leq m^2 - 1 < m^2$ and so it follows that
$$m - 1 \leq \sqrt{m^2 - 1} < m$$
Hence we have that $\lfloor\sqrt{m^2 - 1}\rfloor = m - 1$.